# How to query which RPM package provides a specific version

Tags: rpm

RPM SPEC files know about package versions in both `Requires:` and `Provides:` tags, so inside a SPEC file it's easy to build proper dependency even with mangled names (e.g. to avoid conflicts and allow multiple versions of packages)

As an example package foo provides updated version:

```
Name: foox
Provides: foo = 2
```

and

```
Name: bar5
Requires: foo >= 2
```

works quite well - yum will not install bar5 unless foox is also installed.

My question - how can I query which package provides `foo = 2` from command line?

From the man page of rpm it appears that

> --whatprovides CAPABILITY
>
> ```
> Query all packages that provide the CAPABILITY capability.
> ```
>
> --provides
>
> ```
> List capabilities this package provides.
> ```

Would've sufficed.
I can `rpm -q --provides <package name>` and see the version.
I can even `rpm -q --qf %{VERSION} <package name>` and get only the version.
However, I can't `rpm -q --whatprovides` on the name and version to get the actual package name.

I have also tried `rpm -q --provides foo` but I only get the original foo = 1, even though foox is installed and provides foo = 2.

what I would like is the following magic:

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides "foo = 2"
$ foox
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's close:

```
rpm -q --whatprovides "foo = 2"
```

but it does not accept a version.  To get that, go back a step and format the output from

```
rpm -q --whatprovides foo
```

like this:

```
rpm -q --queryformat "%{VERSION}:%{NAME}\n" --whatprovides foo
```

and filter the result by grep (to select your "2"), and then through sed, to remove the extra version followed by a colon:

```
grep -E '/^2:/' | sed -e 's/^[^:]*://'
```

That gives just the package name.  In practice, you would want the version, release and architecture to *install* the correct dependency.

For reference: *[5.2.5. Determining which package provides a certain capability](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch05s02s05.html)* (Fedora RPM Guide)

Regarding OP's comment that awk would be simpler:

```
awk -F: '{ if ($1 == "2") print $2}'
```

I agree (but from habit working on configure scripts, use awk second to grep/sed, since it is a little less portable).  However, if one wanted to check for packages with versions greater than or equal to a given value, awk would definitely be much simpler, e.g.,

```
awk -F: '{ if ($1 >= 2) print $2}'
```

That occurred to me this morning after I'd already left.  But that type of comparison is probably more common in spec-files than exact matches.  Also, quoting the `"2"` may force awk to treat it as a string rather than a number.  That would not match version `2.0`, but leaving it unquoted — and numeric — would let it match.

@[dave-thompson-085](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/59699/dave-thompson-085) pointed out that enclosing the comparison within the *action* is unnecessary.  That is, the part within `{` and `}` in the preceding is an action, for all lines (since no pattern is given). Quoting from mawk's [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html#h3-1_-Program-structure):

> An AWK program is a sequence of *pattern* *{action}* pairs and  user  function definitions.

and then

```
   A pattern can be:
          BEGIN
          END
          expression
          expression , expression
```

An expression might be a *regular expression*, but could also be an [comparison](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html#h3-2_-Data-types_-conversion-and-comparison).  His suggested improvement is

```
awk -F: '$1>=2{print $2}'
```

Comment: I'd compress the grep and sed to a single sed or awk, but this works. Thanks

Comment: `awk -F: '{ if ($1 == "2") print $2}'`

Comment: yes - I would have added awk if you had requested an inequality, but grep/sed are tools I use most because I start with the simplest tool (most portable) and work upward to meet constraints.

Comment: Even briefer `awk -F: '$1>=2{print $2}'` (or `==` etc as needed).

Comment: yes, that works too (I was keeping the changed version close to the suggested, to make it easier to compare).